# How to get all LDAP users with LdapTemplate

Tags: spring-security, spring-ldap

I'm using spring-security and wish to retrieve all users and all groups to be stored in a reference table so I can quickly look up users without having to consult the LDAP directory. I have created a `LdapAuthoritiesPopulator` implementation mirroring `DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator` with the following additional method:

```java
public final Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAllAuthorities() {
    if (groupSearchBase == null) {
        return new HashSet<>();
    }
    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> roles = ldapTemplate.searchForSingleAttributeValues(
            groupSearchBase,
            allAuthorityFilter,
            new String[0],
            groupRoleAttribute);
    for (String role : roles) {
        if (convertToUpperCase) {
            role = role.toUpperCase();
        }
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(rolePrefix + role));
    }
    return authorities;
}
```

This now allows me to retrieve all groups, `allAuthorityFilter` is a property defaulting to `(&(objectClass=group)(objectCategory=group))`.

I am now trying to achieve the same thing with the users by creating a custom `LdapUserSearch` based of of `FilterBasedLdapUserSearch` with the following additional method:

```java
public List<String> findAllUsers() {
    SpringSecurityLdapTemplate template
            = new SpringSecurityLdapTemplate(contextSource);
    template.setSearchControls(searchControls);
    List<String> r = template.search(searchBase,
                                     allUsersFilter,
                                     new AttributesMapper() {
        @Override
        public Object mapFromAttributes(Attributes atrbts)
                throws NamingException {
            return (String) atrbts.get(userNameAttribute).get();
        }
    });
    return r;
}
```

There are two problems I have with this:

1. If the user-list is large I get `javax.naming.SizeLimitExceededException` which I do not know how to resolve.
2. I want this method to return something like `DirContextOperations` similar to how `searchForUser(String)` works so that my `LdapUserDetailsMapper` implementation can be reused to return all user properties.

I'm finding the documentation for `LdapTemplate` a little hairy and having trouble finding the answers I'm after, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**: I have solved point (2) above by

```java
public List<UserDetails> getAllUserDetails(boolean includeAuthorities) {
    List<UserDetails> r = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DirContextOperations ctx : userSearch.findAllUserOperations()) {
        try {
            Attribute att = ctx.getAttributes().get(usernameAttribute);
            String username = (String) att.get();
            r.add(userMapper.mapUserFromContext(
                    ctx,
                    username,
                    includeAuthorities
                        ? authPop.getGrantedAuthorities(ctx, username)
                        : Collections.<GrantedAuthority>emptySet()));
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            LOG.warn("Username attribute " + usernameAttribute + " not found!");
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

In my `UserSearch` implementation I have:

```java
public List<DirContextOperations> findAllUserOperations() {
    SpringSecurityLdapTemplate template = new SpringSecurityLdapTemplate(contextSource);
    template.setSearchControls(searchControls);
    return template.search(searchBase,
                           allUsersFilter, new ContextMapper() {
        @Override
        public Object mapFromContext(Object o) {
            return (DirContextOperations) o;
        }
    });
}
```

However I have not solved point #1. If I need to batch this somehow then that is fine as long as there is a way to tell `LdapTemplate` where to resume on subsequent calls.